# Basic LibGDX Game won't run

Tags: java, libgdx

**Relevant background information**

I'm developing a game in Java & LibGDX. Well, I started a project. I made a game with LibGDX about a year ago before. I made a new project with the Gradle setup and imported it into eclipse. I ran it and it didn't work

**The problem**

In the basic template it displays the badlogic image. It says it's not there or it can't find it.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:148)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at com.kymed.dank.rpg.GameState.create(GameState.java:16)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: badlogic.jpg (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:145)
```

Though it's in the assets folder

Comment: Make sure your assets are set correctly in eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195973/5007340

Comment: @exenza didn't work, eclipse said it's already there or something like that. Didn't let me add.

Comment: Did you import the project by gradle or by existing projects ?

Comment: Are you trying to run the Desktop version of your game?

Comment: Yeah @bornander

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the working directory of your runtime configuration for the desktop launch to the `assets` folder, if you have included Android in your project. Otherwise, the assets folder should be `core/assets`.

If that does not fix it, then catch the exception under the debugger, and inspect its nested exception for clues.